# How to get product details and category id in shipping method?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, fedex

I want to get product detail and category of that product, which product is added in cart. But I want those product in shipping method. I am using Fedex Shipping method. I want those details in this function.

app\code\core\Mage\Usa\Model\Shipping\Carrier\Fedex.php

```
protected function _prepareRateResponse($response)
{
     // Need Product details and category id of that product
}
```

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, please don't change the core class. Extend it from an extension or at least copy the file to the `local` directory.

You can access the quote object in the shipping method to get the product you want.

```
$quote= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) 
{
   $product = $item->getProduct(); // the product instance
   var_dump($product->getName());
   var_dump($product->getCategoryIds());
}
```

Comment: Magel, Thanks for your post. But I need Cart details. As well as I need product qty.

Comment: `var_dump($item->getData());` will show you the data available of the item (such as qty) and you can perform the same getData call on the quote item

Answer (score 1):

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
    $proid=$item->getProduct()->getId();
    $categoryIds=$item->getProduct()->getCategoryIds($proid);
    foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId)
    {

        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

    }
    echo  "category: ".$category->getName();
    echo '<br/>';
    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";
}
```